# Google Cloud SQL import - ERROR: HTTPError 403: The client is not authorized to make this request

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-sql

I trying to import a database stored in the Cloud Storage using the command:

```
gcloud sql instances import instance-name gs://connect-to-the-cloud-sql.appspot.com/my-cloud-sql-instance-backup
```

But, I am getting error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.sql.instances.import) HTTPError 403: The client is not authorized to make this request.
```

I've already logged in using:

```
gcloud auth login
```

Comment: Double check the project name.

Comment: Project name is correct. I was able to use `gcloud sql instances export my-cloud-sql-instance gs://connect-to-the-cloud-sql.appspot.com/my-cloud-sql-instance-backup`

Answer (score 12):

Make sure the instance-name is correct. I had the same error, it went away as soon as I corrected the instance-name.

Comment: In my case I had been trying the command `gcloud sql users list` with the `--instance=project:zone:instance-name`, and go this same error, when I tried just `--instance=instance-name` it worked

Comment: @bryant same here

Answer (score 6):

I had this problem, my instance name was correct. Turns out I was in the wrong GCP project. Make sure you switch to the correct [target] project or use the project argument:

```
gcloud sql instances export my-cloud-sql-instance gs://connect-to-the-cloud-sql.appspot.com/my-cloud-sql-instance-backup --project=<your target project>
```

Answer (score 4):

In my case it was because the cloud sql instance service account didn't have the correct permissions on the storage bucket I was trying to import from.

[From the docs](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/import-export/importing):

1. Describe the instance you are importing to:

   ```
   gcloud sql instances describe [INSTANCE_NAME]
   ```
2. Copy the `serviceAccountEmailAddress` field.
3. Use `gsutil iam` to grant the `legacyBucketWriter` and `objectViewer` Cloud IAM roles to the service account for the bucket.
4. Import the database:

   ```
   gcloud sql import sql [INSTANCE_NAME] gs://[BUCKET_NAME]/[IMPORT_FILE_NAME] \
                           --database=[DATABASE_NAME]
   ```

Comment: REALLY RECOMMENDED: check the docs listed by @inostia

Comment: Nope, even this answer doesn't solve it.

Answer (score 1):

It might sound too obvious, but your service account really may be missing access rights for importing data. Check that it has correct `cloudsql.instances.import` policy installed on IAM&Admin page.

Comment: Nope,, it has SQL admin at this point just to cover all bases but still has the issue

Answer (score 0):

New step by step:

```bash
gcloud sql instances describe name-instance | grep serviceAccountEmailAddress

# output: serviceAccount:account@gcp-sa.com

gsutil iam ch serviceAccount:account@gcp-sa.com:roles/storage.legacyBucketWriter gs://bucket-destino
gsutil iam ch serviceAccount:account@gcp-sa.com:roles/storage.objectViewer gs://bucket-destino

# -----------en vm linux--gcp------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
gcloud init (id-project-bucket-destino hacer default en vm proyecto de bucket donde se guardara info)
gcloud config set project id-project-bucket-destino

gcloud sql export sql --project=id-project-instance name-instance gs://bucket-destino/sqldump.sql \
--database=name-database \
--offload

# ----------cron job in linux------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#!/bin/sh

#make directory in Cloud storage

datedirect=$(date '+%d-%m-%Y')

echo $datedirect

touch file5

gsutil cp -r ./file5 gs://bucket-destino/$datedirect/

gcloud config set project id-project-bucket-destino

gcloud sql export sql --project=id-project-instance name-instance gs://bucket-destino/sqldump.sql \
--database=name-database \
--offload
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: also no, doesn't work, nothing works, literally nothing, I've never encountered so many wrong answers in my life but I don't know what the right answer is

Answer (score 0):

In Cloud Console go to IAM & Admin > IAM, find the service account you're using, and edit its roles to add Cloud SQL Client and Cloud SQL Admin. If you can't find the service account, then use Grant Access to create it, with the aforementioned roles.

@inostia in another answer mentions using `gcloud sql instances describe [INSTANCE_NAME]` to get the service account from `serviceAccountEmailAddress`. That might work for you but if you're impersonating, *e.g.*

```
gcloud auth application-default login --impersonate-service-account local-development@adstudio-sandbox1.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

then you want to use the impersonating service account.