# Google Cloud aiohttp error when connecting from compute engine to database in Python

Tags: python-3.x, linux, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, aiohttp

I'm trying to connect my Compute Engine to a MySQL database, both hosted through Google Cloud. The program to obtain data works in the Compute Engine, but when I try to store the information into the DB I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 81, in <module>
    db="products"
  File "/home/jasper_wijnhoven/supermarktspider/googlec/cloud/sql/connector/connector.py", line 95, in connect
    return icm.connect(driver, timeout, **kwargs)
  File "/home/jasper_wijnhoven/supermarktspider/googlec/cloud/sql/connector/instance_connection_manager.py", line 328, in connect
    connection = connect_future.result(timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 432, in result
    return self.__get_result()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 384, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
  File "/home/jasper_wijnhoven/supermarktspider/googlec/cloud/sql/connector/instance_connection_manager.py", line 356, in _connect
    instance_data: InstanceMetadata = await self._current
  File "/home/jasper_wijnhoven/supermarktspider/googlec/cloud/sql/connector/instance_connection_manager.py", line 251, in _get_instance_data
    metadata, ephemeral_cert = await asyncio.gather(metadata_task, ephemeral_task)
  File "/home/jasper_wijnhoven/supermarktspider/googlec/cloud/sql/connector/refresh_utils.py", line 88, in _get_metadata
    resp = await client_session.get(url, headers=headers, raise_for_status=True)
  File "/home/jasper_wijnhoven/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 625, in _request
    resp.raise_for_status()
  File "/home/jasper_wijnhoven/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aiohttp/client_reqrep.py", line 1005, in raise_for_status
    headers=self.headers,
aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientResponseError: 403, message='Forbidden', url=URL('hidden for obvious reasons')
```

I'm not sure what's wrong, since when I try to connect through the URL myself I get a 401 error. I followed the steps and whitelisted my CE IP for connection with the DB. Can someone give me a pointer?

Here's the code used to set up the connector:

```
connection = connector.connect(
    "single-router-309308:europe-west4:supermarkt-database",
    "mysql-connector",
    user="root",
    password="hidden again :)",
    db="products"
)
```

Comment: The `Forbidden` error may occur due to a number of reasons. 
I'd review this thread about [403 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46504465/google-cloud-sql-import-error-httperror-403-the-client-is-not-authorized-to) as it may provide good insights.

You may want to recreate your Cloud SQL permissions to make sure everything is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Check to make sure the service account you are using has the correct permissions:

1. It should have the `Cloud SQL client` role or higher
2. The Cloud SQL Admin API should be enabled

Comment: Turned out I needed to set os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = root_path + "key file.json" as well, otherwise the authorisation didn't work.

However, now I get an ERRNO 13: Permission denied exception. I do have the roles for both my users set to Owner & Cloud SQL Client, but I never specify which user connects. Is that something that needs to be done as well?

Comment: The README contains some info about how it finds your IAM user: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-python-connector#authentication